# Change value of object property inside javascript object affect other object

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I would like to change a property of an object, inside an object. But, when I did that, other object property that created using the same prototype also changed.

The code is as follows:

```
var a = {
  x: { y: 'foo' }
}

var b = Object.create(a)
var c = Object.create(a)

console.log(a.x.y) // 'foo'
console.log(b.x.y) // 'foo'
console.log(c.x.y) // 'foo'

b.x.y = 'bar'

var d = Object.create(a)

console.log(a.x.y) // 'bar'
console.log(b.x.y) // 'bar'
console.log(c.x.y) // 'bar'
console.log(d.x.y) // 'bar'
```

I think the problem is because all objects referring the same `x`, therefore changing `y` from any object reflected in all objects. Can anyone explain what really happened here, perhaps with reference and suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: `x` is just a reference to the same object. One way around it would be simply to create `x` as a property using the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) `propertiesObject` parameter

Answer (score 2):

`x` is an object, that is why it is referenced by a pointer and not by the value like the string is.

Try the following as a workaround:

```
b.x = { y: 'bar' } // instead of b.x.y = 'bar'
```

this creates a new object `x` which will be different from others

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = function() {
    this.x = { y: 'foo '};
}

var b = new a();
var c = new a();

b.x.y = 'bar';
```

You will just reference the same object (reference pointer to a place in memory), and modify the object that each object reference to. What you probably want to do is **create** a new object that are isolated.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object and sets its prototype to the first parameter passed in. In your case that's an instance of an object (`a`), but you use that same instace as the prototype for `b` & `c`. So... when accessing members of the prototype of `b`, you really accessing members of `a` (via prototypical inheritance). Modifying that applies to all inheriting objects

In order to achieve the inheritance you tried, while using `Object.create` AND separating all instances, do this:

```js
function a() {
  this.x = { y: 'foo' }
}

var b = Object.create(new a())
var c = Object.create(new a())

//console.log(a.x.y) // a is not an object, it's a function, or a "type"
console.log(b.x.y) // 'foo'
console.log(c.x.y) // 'foo'

b.x.y = 'bar'

var d = Object.create(new a())

//console.log(a.x.y) // a is not an object, it's a function, or a "type"
console.log(b.x.y) // 'bar'
console.log(c.x.y) // 'foo'
console.log(d.x.y) // 'foo'
```