# Why does changing the value of a property change the value for all similarly named properties in an array?

Tags: javascript

Why does changing the value of a property change the value for all similar properties in an array and how do I get it to work right without using the `this` keyword for `'name'`?

```js
let Object = {
 'name' : 'Test Object'
}

let Array = []

Array.push(Object)
Array.push(Object)
Array.push(Object)

Array[0]['name'] = 'Changed'

console.log(Array) // expect only the first name to change, but all 3 change...
```

Comment: Non-primitives such as objects are passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change value of object property inside javascript object affect other object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913725/change-value-of-object-property-inside-javascript-object-affect-other-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't changing "similarly named" objects, you are changing the same object.

For non-primitives (basically everything that isn't a string, number, or boolean), they are passed by reference. That means when you add them to something like an array or pass them to a function, you are basically passing their address. If you pass it 3 times, they all point to the same address; there is still only one copy. Change one, and you change them all.

```js
const a = { b: 1 };
const arr = [a, a, a];

// All the same object
console.log(arr[0] === arr[1], arr[1] === arr[2], a === arr[0]);

a.b = 5;

// All 3 changed, because it is the same thing
console.log(arr.map(a => a.b));

function someFunc(obj) { obj.b = 10 };

someFunc(a);

// changed from inside function, same object
console.log(a.b);
```

If you want to create a handful of objects that all start the same, but then are able to change afterwards, you need to create the objects in a loop:

```js
const template = { name: 'a' };
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr.push({ ...template }); // or: arr.push(Object.create({}, template))
}

arr[1].name = 'b';
arr[2].name = 'c';
console.log(arr);
```

Or, even more concisely:

```js
// Creates a new Array with 3 records and then puts a copy of the template in each.
const template = { name: 'a' };
const arr = new Array(3).fill(1).map(() => ({ ...template }));
// or (without needing template variable):
// const arr = new Array(3).fill(1).map(() => ({ name: 'a' }))

arr[1].name = 'b';
arr[2].name = 'c';

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: why this answer got downvoted? i dont find anything , it clearly explains the main thing to understand, voting up

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks, I was confused as well.

Comment: someone on downvote spree, i so much hate such people :/ this is actually preventing a good answer to be highlighted, which is the main reason for having SO, a good answer should be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Not the downvoter, but likely because this question has been asked so many times before - better to close as a duplicate of a canonical question than to answer

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `Array.push(Object)`, you're pushing a reference to the same object into the array 3 times.  Push does not make a copy of `Object` - only 1 `Object` exists.

If you want 3 identical objects in an array, try something like this:

```
let vArray = []

for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    //We're going to loop this 3 times, creating 3 different
    //objects and pushing each of them into the array

    let vObject = {
        'name' : 'Test Object'
    }

    vArray.push(vObject)
}

vArray[0]['name'] = 'Changed'

console.log(vArray) // Only the first one will have been changed.
```

Comment: This is exactly the same syntax I had, except it's inside a for loop, why does this suddenly work?

Comment: this aint going to work as you are using revered names `Array` for a var and will give `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined` for the line `Array[0]['name'] = 'Changed'`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You're right - I was using the same names as the OP so it was clear what I was referencing in the context of his question. I've slightly changed them so that it can be copy/pasted more easily.

Comment: @Gallaxhar Because the creation of `vObject` is inside the loop, it is creating a new object each time (`let` releases the old `vObject` variable and creates a new one). In your question, you create a single object and then reference it 3 times in the array.  In my example, I'm creating 3 separate objects and referencing each of them in the array.

Answer (score -1):

The answer I was looking for was to change the syntax in my answer to `Array.push({...Object})`. This creates a 'new' object to be pushed, with only 5 additional characters...

I didn't know 'object spread syntax' essentially did this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to further explain how to populate an array with copies of an object instead of three references to the same.